# Equivalents of PHP PDO in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, sqlite

Is there something like PHP PDO for Java? So I can develop for SQLite in the beginning and later on switch to MySQL or PostgreSQL.

**UPDATE:** No I didn't search for *Java database abstraction* because I didn't know what to search for

Comment: Did you Google `Java database abstraction`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Java Database Connectivity**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)

JDBC is a Java-based data access technology (Java Standard Edition platform) from Sun Microsystems. It is an acronym as it is unofficially referred to as Java Database Connectivity, with DB being universally recognized as the abbreviation for database. This technology is an API for the Java programming language that defines how a client may access a database. It provides methods for querying and updating data in a database. JDBC is oriented towards relational databases. A JDBC-to-ODBC bridge enables connections to any ODBC-accessible data source in the JVM host environment.